# Virtualbox restart error

Tags: virtualbox

I just installed Linux Mint 17.1 on my virtualbox4.3.22. At the end of installation I was prompted to restart. I hit restart and it goes to a blank dark screen with this text "mint@mint ~ $". I am not what this means, but if someone can tell me what's going on and how to fix it, I will greatly appreciate it. See image below. By the way I am running Ubuntu 14.10, 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes with fresh installs.
In the upper left corner of the dead window Right-click on the small icon and choose power off computer.
Wait a bit, and start your Mint again.
Run the updates, and your system should work nicely.
My guess is that its the guest client settings that's not quite up to date.
As a bonus you will probably get the VM display driver so you can run it large.

Comment: Thanks Ken! Fortunately, I have it fixed and running now. I re-installed mint in the VirtualBox. When it got to the stage where I had to restart the system, I pull the disc out and hit the restart button. The screen froze when I hit the restart button. So I close the window and saved the state VM state and then shotdown. Then I power up and waited. As it powers up, of course the black screen came up and stayed on for about 1min and suddenly the linux mint logo popped up in the middle of the dark screen. This is when I knew everything is working fine. Thanks!\